# Not able to create key from openssl

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, csr

I'm trying to create key using below command

```
openssl genrsa -out /danny/mykey.key 2048 -config /etc/pki/t1s/openssl.cnf
```

but am getting below error

```
warning, not much extra random data, consider using the -rand option Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus 
89660:error:24064064:random number generator:SSLEAY_RAND_BYTES:PRNG not seeded:md_rand.c:512:
You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://openssl.org/faq
```

can anyone suggest what's wrong happening ? how can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you read the FAQ? It's the first entry.

Comment: @stark, just saw that..but how can I use this rand option with my command ?

Comment: Have you checked your openssl.cnf configuration? Maybe rand option incorrect.